# Trouble coverting image to []uint8

Tags: go

How can I extract raw []uint8 from an image?

Comment: What output size do you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure what the output size should be, but for a picture thats only a few hundred KB, an output of []uint8 that's 30 MB seems way too large.

Comment: It's not impossible that an 8 megapixel image (e.g 4000x2000) is compressed into a 300 KB JPEG (depends on the compression level). If you take this example, 8 megapixel each having 3 byte (RGB), that results in 24 million bytes => 24 MB. If there's an alpha channel, that is 32 MB. I see nothing unusal here.

Comment: Also if the source is not a photo (but e.g. a generated image), if it has wide areas having the same pixel, formats such as PNG can make it really small, yet if you decode it, it will have the same amount of pixels,,,

Comment: The code converts the data bytes to space separated decimal values.  Is that your actual goal, or did you intend to write the bytes as is to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size on an 8-bit integer is, by definition, 8 bits (or 1 byte).

(Editing to remove erroneous information, which I'll repost for posterity below.)

The string representation being output is not one character per number - it's several (for example, the int you list first - `65` - is being represented by *three* characters - a 6, a 5, and a space.  That would increase the expected size threefold, from 300k to 900k.

As for the rest, I would think that (as [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) said in a comment) image compression may be the culprit.

---

(The irrelevant information I'd initially posted as part of my answer was:

> Go has two character types, `byte` and `rune`.  A byte being used to store a character is the same size as a byte being used to store an integer - both are 8 bits.  But a character being stored as a `rune` is going to be 32 bits (see https://www.callicoder.com/golang-basic-types-operators-type-conversion/).  So, if the characters being written out are `rune`s, that would explain a four-fold increase in size (because 32 / 8 = 4)...

Comment: Yes, the rest is right, the stuff about runes is a red herring.